# 2D Platform physics system with deltaTime

Tags: 2d, physics, movement, physics-engine

I'm implementing my physics handler in my own 2D "Platform" game.
My main problem is that when the timestep ( deltaTime ) changes, maybe to some tiny lag spike or something like that, the running entity visibly changes its speed ( running at top speed, actually) and that is really annoying to see. Other than that, if my game run slower (for example at ~33 fps) the entity moves definitely slower, which is, of course, not good at all, and moves 'lagging', in a completely not smooth way.
I use a **variable time step** and I limit FPS only if I have to do some test (for example simulating lag).
The game, and so the timestep calculation, is made with C++ and SDL2 but I think this issue is not language-specific. By the way this is how I calculate the timestep:

```
double last=0, delay=0;
while (running) {
    Uint32 now = SDL_GetTicks();
    if (now > last) {
        delay=now-last;
        last=now;
    }
    view->update(delay); // This is where every game logic takes place
    //... Do other stuff (clear screen, clear inputs, swap buffers)
}
```

Generally, this code works just fine, if my fps are less, then the deltaTime (`delay` in the code) increases. And that's ok. On the other hand there is a huge problem which is, of course, affecting my physic system: if my game runs faster than a certain number of fps (i.e. fps >= 1000 ) then, not matter what is the specific value, `delay` is always 1.
This makes a game session running at 1000 fps fast 1/2 of a session running at 2000fps. I know those values are extremely high and that my game is running like that just because now it's empty, but I think I can't ignore this problem. What if a super high extreme gaming machine tries to run my game ?

**Now let's talk about physics:**
My physics engine is really simple. It is 2D and, for now, I implemented only the x-Axis algorithm. My entity has a 2D vector holding speed (`speed.x` and `speed.y` ), a top speed (`maxSpeed`) and, of course, a position).

My engine works like this:

```
//Code executed in every frame:
if (fabs(speed.x) > 0 ) {
    speed.x /=  delta; //Simulate a very high friction

    if (fabs(speed.x) > maxSpeed) { //check if exceed the top speed
        //if so, set the speed to the top speed with the same sign
        speed.x = (maxSpeed * delta) * sgn(speed.x); 
    }

   //Finally change the position according to the speed
    x += speed.x*delta;
}
```

That is what I use to simulate a physic system, where `sgn` is custom function which returns 1 if the value is positive, -1 otherwise. I know the friction is very high, but at the moment I do not care too much.

The last piece of code I use, is the code to make the entity actually move. To do so I use this piece of code:

```
if (input->isKeyDown(KEY_D))
    speed.x += acceleration.x * delta;
else if (input->isKeyDown(KEY_A))
    speed.x -= acceleration.x*delta;
```

In this code `acceleration` is like a constant, it's simply a value. 
Now the code works fine in very general terms but the problems are:

- Even a little change to delta (delay, variable time step) makes the entity visibly change his own speed (I guess it's related to top speed).
- If my game runs on average of 30 -- 45 fps, the entity moves, but at a different top speed and the transition is verry laggy.
- At a certain point delta becomes constant and that breaks up every physic logic.

I think everything is related to how I use my delta (delay) in each frane

Comment: The canonical answer to questions like these is an excellent article called [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

Comment: are you using SDL_Delay(delay); ? SDL_Delay only guarantees that the program will pause for at least "delay" time but it could wait a bit longer.